# Rewrite Proxy where the destination host ip is passed in the URI

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I need to create a proxy rewrite in **NGINX** where the rewrite URL is composed of data included in the URI of the request. For instance:

Given the URL:

http://proxyhost:5555/go/**222.222.222.222**/action/etc

The rewrite should head to:

http://**222.222.222.222**:6666/action/etc

Is this possible in NGIX ?

I can do this on apache httpd but so far I have not figured out how to do this on nginx

(apache specific example):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule "^go/(.*)/action/(.*)$" "http://$1:6666/action/$2"  [P]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `location` block should do the work.

```
location ~ ^/go/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/(action/.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$1:6666/$2;
}
```

I assume here that the destination host is always specified as an IP address. The regex loosely matches an IP address. It can be made more or less specific if you like.

Anyway, this is done in nginx by using regex capture in the `location` directive, and then using the captured variables in `proxy_pass` statement.